# Always content to stay in middle of next child?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I am using Boostrap 3 for some website I am creating, what i want to make i next.

Here is a code

```
<section class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src=
      "http://webdesignledger.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/logo_design_4.jpg" /></div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenean eu sollicitudin felis. Vestibulum vitae imperdiet nibh. Curabitur euismod
        auctor libero sit amet varius. Maecenas eu porta libero. Pellentesque et sem et
        turpis scelerisque hendrerit vel ac nibh. Nam tempor ullamcorper scelerisque.
        Aenean accumsan ac justo ac laoreet. Aliquam eu libero</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<section>
```

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gSmRw/

On big screen text always to be allign in the middle of the picture, i dont know how big picture will it be, maybe small maybe big, any idea, or help.
Here is picture what i want to make and how it has to look up

[image]

Comment: `What i need is on big screen text always to be allign in the middle of the picture`. what???

Comment: How do you mean what, please take a look at fiddle and take a look a picture i have send :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gSmRw/3/

I've basically added a calss `table` to the `.container` element and changed the CSS of this container to be styled as table.

it's important to give the image div wrapper a width of `1%` so the cell will not be wider than the image.